# What websites provide streaming services for dubbed anime?

Tags: resources

I want to know which websites out there provide legal streaming services for dubbed anime. Among the series I'd like to watch are Death Note and Fullmetal Alchemist, but I'd really like to be able to see whole seasons.

Comment: You can try some of the sites listed [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal/923#923)

Comment: It may be useful to precise where you are living. Services are not always available everywhere and most are country specific.

Answer (score 3):

The following streaming services provide a combination of subbed and dubbed anime. Most of them will require some sort of subscription to access the content. Availability is indicated by region.

US = United States; CA = Canada; AU = Australia; NZ = New Zealand; FR = France; UK = United Kingdom; IE = Ireland.

- [Animax](http://animaxtv.co.uk/) for UK/IE
- [The Anime Network](http://www.theanimenetwork.com/Watch-Anime/Category/Dubbed) for US
- [Anime Lab](https://www.animelab.com/home) for AU/NZ
- [Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/) for US/CA
- [Dybex](http://www.dybex.com/fr/) for FR
- [Funimation](http://www.funimation.com/) for US/CA
- [Hulu](http://www.hulu.com/) for US
- [Neon Alley (Viz)](http://www.viz.com/anime/streaming) for US/CA
- [Netflix](https://www.netflix.com/) for US
- [Wakanim](http://www.wakanim.tv/fr/v2/discover) for FR

Comment: You may find some more [here](http://myanimelist.net/featured/1617).

Answer (score 2):

I believe Cruchyroll.com, netflix, hulu.com (hulu plus), amazon video service, crackle all have dubbed.  They're not always clearly labeled though on what is dubbed and what is not.  Youtube also has legal streaming channels for pay you can watch episodes.